# Can a Interrupt written in a kernel module (Linux) notify a running program in Qt? Without userspace program waiting/polling?

Tags: c, embedded-linux, interrupt

Is there anyway an interrupt coming from a kernel module can notify a Qt-embedded program running in userspace? Without using ioctl's "wait_event_interruptible()"?

I would like my program to just run as normal without having to "wait" or take a poll to check if the interrupt happened. Once the interrupt happened the program would react

This question is similar to mine [How kernel notify a user space program an interrupt occurrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899055/how-kernel-notify-a-user-space-program-an-interrupt-occurrs) but he is using "wait_event_interruptible()"

Thanks

Comment: You can enqueue signal (not directly from handler, but you can). There will be some delay between interrupt and signal handler call.

Comment: You can also have a thread which waits on a blocking read (ie, has extremely low cost) and sets a flag when the read returns.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys will look into both of them

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with the netlink (libnl). In driver all you need is the pid number to unicast message to. And from application you can use the socket's recvmsg() to wait for the even to occur.

- [app]----{send a message to driver}---> [driver] (driver now knows the pid & saves it)
- [app]------{blocking recvmsg}---------> waiting for the event to be raise
- [app]<--------{message with payload}--- [driver] (sends the event info as unicast to the pid)

hope this helps,

regards

Comment: I thought about doing that however "you can use the socket's recvmsg() to wait for the even to occur." I still have to wait or poll the netlink socket to check if a message was sent

Comment: This is a possible solution mentioned by @Chris Stratton in comments, If you use a thread it will block in socket's recvmsg(), but will resume as soon as the kernel module sends the event notification.

The best part is you can again block recvmsg() in that thread to receive same event occurrence again without sending any data to the kernel module.